# Which method is called on clicking "Mini Apps Tray" in galaxy tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to finish my current activity  on click of any app (i.e., calculator, calender, etc) from "Mini Apps Tray" in galaxy tab.

I have noticed that onWindowFocusChanged() is called when app is clicked but using this to finish the app is not a good idea as any system generated interrupts may let it to be called.

Even I cannot disable this Mini Apps Tray.

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific method which is called when the user opens one mini app. This feature is implemented by Samsung and we cannot know any detail about how it works in a deeper level.

I thought that `onWindowFocusChanged()` could solve this problem. You've said that it is called in other situations than on the opening of the applications right? Can you see any difference in the `Boolean hasFocus` attribute that is passed to the method?

Comment: It gives me false when the activity is out of focus.

Comment: Right now I check the hasFocus of onWindowFocusChanged() and set a flag to check whether the onPause is called or not and then finish the activity accordingly. This is working for me but I don't find this as a concrete solution.

Comment: I agree with you. This seems like a work-around solution. But when you deal with features that you dont have any documentation or any help by it's developers, you should see the solution with better eyes! :)